# Designing Correction Table

Tags: mysql

I have a correction table that is in a PDF that I want to put into a MySQL table or tables but have no clue where to start could someone start me on right path.

The PDF is located - http://homedistiller.org/correctiontable.pdf   - page 2 and 3 of PDF

I would need to reference temperature which is at top of table and compare against ABV% on left of table to get actual %.

Thanks for anyhelp

Comment: The first thing to get a grip of is normalization - this table is far from normalized!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a simple table with 3 columms:

```
CREATE TABLE correction (
    temperature INT,
    abv DECIMAL(4,1),
    actual INT
)
```

You can then query that table like

```
SELECT actual FROM correction WHERE temperature=25 AND abv=60.7
```

However, you will need to get that data into the SQL table somehow *(which would trouble me more than the table-layout)*

Comment: What happens if one of the two inputs doesn't exactly match what's in the table? With the paper table, you would interpolate (exactly or guesstimate by eye). With a DB lookup, you'd have to round inputs to the nearest (row and column) value that's in the table. How was this table generated in the first place -- is there a function `corr = f(temp, abv)`? That might be a lot faster and a lot easier to set up.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I was over thinking it...  As far as input guess I will have to do it manually :(. Phil I think rounding up or down will work for my purposes.